# Word background color doesn't persist for .dotm template docs

Tags: microsoft-word

I have **Office Professional Plus 2019**.

There is a background color that I want all my Word docs to have by default, whenever creating a new/blank doc: `227-221-191`. This is easy to do in Word: `Design -> Page Color`

The problem is that when I set up my doc this way and save it as a `.dotm` file into `C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Normal.dotm`, the background color apparently didn't take. When I launch Word and create a new/blank doc, the background color is white instead of the color I set. But I know that it (in some way at least) used the `Normal.dotm` I just created, because I had also changed the font and margins in the `.dotm`, and those got used in the new doc as expected.

Why is my background color not being used/invoked that I had set (and saved) in `Normal.dotm`?? Is this a bug in word?

Answer (score 0):

*You cannot save a separate file from within Word as Normal.dotm.* **Period.**
You should not try to do it outside of Word, either. Only Word can create a fully functional normal template.

1. You can save you template with a different name and use that as the basis for new documents where you want this background.
2. You can OPEN the normal template and make the change to that, then save it.
3. It is possible, using macros, to have another template work as the default template for new documents.